# Let G be the language of all string over {0,1} that do not contain a pair of 1s that are separated by a odd number of symbols.

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

This is a questions in book, Introduction-To-The-Theory-Of-Computation-Michael-Sipse, Third edition, P85. This is not hw problem(solution is given)
So based on the given hit, we negate it first as 
F'={w|w contains a pair of 1s that are separated by an odd number of symbols} over {0,1}. and given solution draw the NFA below.

[image]

My question is, 
what does it mean by "a odd number of symbols"?

is the given graph graph correct, (I don't think so, since it doesn't have any accept states)

Comment: I don't see what's ambiguous about "an odd number of symbols" (though perhaps "*separated by* an odd number of symbols" could need some explaining). 10101 is a pair of ones separated by three symbols (which is an odd number of symbols since three is odd). It also contains two instances of a pair of ones separated by one symbol. It has passed the test for membership in $F'$ in three different ways. $q_3$ should be an accept state.

Answer (score 1):

By "a pair of 1s separated by an odd number of symbols", it means two `1`s with an odd number of symbols (`{0, 1}`) *between* them.

E.g.:
`111` has three pairs of `1`s. The one formed by the first and the last `1` (**1**1**1**) is separated by an odd number of symbols (`1`). The other two, formed by the first and the middle one (**11**1), and the middle one and the last (1**11**) are NOT separated by an odd number of symbols, since they have 0 symbols between one another.

The state diagram you provided is, indeed, missing an accept state, which should be `q3`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I doubt about the graph provided as it accepts number of 1s more than 2. Mathematically (please correct me if I am wrong) for the given language np string may have more than 2 1s. Because in any combination of 1s in a string which has more than 2, let say 3 1s than at least 1 pair of this 1s will be separated by odd number of symbols. Here is the proof: let say positions of 3 consecutive 1s in a string are n,m and k in increasing order. Number of symbols are m-n-1, k-m-1 and k-n-1. if m-n-1 and k-m-1 are odd (both) or even, then k-n-1 is odd. And if any of   m-n-1 and k-m-1 is odd (but not as in upper case both) then we already have 2 1s which are separated by odd number of symbols. So we cannot have more than two 1s in string for given language.